# Microstrategy 9.x - formatting column (metrics and attributes) headers in document grid/graph

Tags: grid, formatting, document, microstrategy

I have a document with several grid/graps objects (all in grid visualization).
I need to chage the color of the columns headers.

In the picture they are black. I cannot find a way to make them red as the grid header[image]

---

If i try to rigt clic on an attribute in edit modality (document) this is what i see (no formatting oprtions):

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the background color of the columns headers? and what happen if you change the background color of a single metric? Are the columns metrics or is an attribute?

Comment: I dont know what happens if i change the color since i cannot do that.
The fist column, grey, is an attribute, the others, white, are metrics.

Comment: what do you mean you can't? formatting settings are applied from the most generic to the most specific, so default formatting for Metric Headers is overwritten by the formatting setting for a specific metric.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in **editable mode** in order to get the "**Advanced formatting" options** from the secondary menu (triggered on right clic)
Have you tried that?
You get some formatting options from the design mode, but not as thorough as from Editable mode.
Editable mode will appear to you on the toolbar with an icon resembling a written paper and a pencil.